# ¿Cómo actualizo la pagina automáticamente?

Tags: html, mvc, spring-boot

Tengo un proyecto Spring MVC en el que cargo una web donde aparecen todos los clientes, cada uno tiene un boton de eliminar. El problema es que eliminar pero no actualiza la web por lo que no aparece eliminado a no  ser que yo refresque manualmente. alguna idea de como hacerlo?os dejo unas pocas cosas
controlador

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public String eliminarMedico(@RequestParam String dni) {
    try {
        sCliente.eliminar(dni);
    } catch (ExcepcionServicio ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "redirect:all";
}
```

La página web (HTML):

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>All Clientes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Todos los clientes</h1>
    <div class="container my-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div th:switch="${list}" class="container my-5">                        
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h2 th:case="null">No record found !!</h2>
                        <div th:case="*">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Dni</th>
                                        <th>nombre</th>
                                        <th>Apellido</th>
                                        <th>Fecha Nacimineto</th>                                           
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <th:block th:each="cliente : ${list}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td th:text="${cliente.dni}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${cliente.nombre}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${cliente.apellido}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${cliente.fNacimiento}"></td>                                         
                                        <td>
                                            <form action="delete" method="post">
                                                <button type=submit th:value="${cliente.dni}" name="dni" class="btn btn-primary"> 
                                                    <i class="fas fa-user-times ml-2"></i></button>
                                            </form>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </th:block>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

No sé si necesitáis algo mas

Comment: Podrias recargar la página con javascript con la funcion `location.reload()`

Comment: agrega parte de tu controlador js, para ver que haces despues de eliminar, porque tan solo podrias llamar de nuevo el end-point que trae tus datos

Comment: @Charls y como hago eso

Comment: @christian como mezco javascrip con esto? dodne meto eso?

Comment: Solamente enlace un script de js a tu html y escucha el evento del click cuando haya un click en el boton de eliminar recargas la página, au  que también y mejor es la opción que dice @Charls, es hacer nuevamente la petición al endpoint para traer los datos (algo parecido a AJAX)

Comment: @christian ni idea de copmo hacer eso he probado a meter en el boton  onclick="location.reload()" pero no funcipona no recarga la web